# Deny change billing address customer

Tags: magento2, billing-address

This title is somehow misleading. I will explain the what I want to achieve.

I know it is possible by default to change the billing address on checkout. Since we are only selling to business clients I kinda want to disable that overall.

The billing address that they provide during the registration should not be editable without us knowing. OR they should not be able to order without a valid VAT id filled in. But even so when they have filled in a valid VAT id we still need to check those (otherwise we have problems with the law).

How it works now :

On viewing our website they can not see prices , after a quick registration we are able to manually see if they have filled in a valid VAT id and therefor putting them in a group manually (since we manually check before allowing them to see prices). When they we have putted them in a group and checked the VAT they can see prices and order. But now everything what happens before has no effect. They can still decide to order without VAT at the checkout and change the address.

Any solutions ?

Would really help me out!

Answer (score 6):

I think you are asking two questions. I'll try to answer the first one.
This is how I tried to always use the default billing address:

As far as I know a billing address is tied to the chosen payment method.
In order to disallow the customer to change the billing address, I made two changes:

1. Configure the payment method not to use a billing address
2. Add an interceptor plugin to the *setBillingAddress* function of the *\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote* class which always inserts the default billing address
   The interceptor is needed, because the standard shipping address is still used instead of the standard billing address.

1.

This can be accomplished by overriding the isBillingAddressRequired property of the checkout layout. For example when using the Magento_OfflinePayments module as a payment option:
Copy the xml code of *magento2ce/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml* to */app/design/frontend/{YOUR_VENDOR}/{YOUR_THEME}/Magento_OfflinePayments/layout/checkout_index_index.xml* and set the true booleans to false.
This

2.

I used http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system as a guide for setting up the Interceptor:

```
<?php
namespace {YOUR_VENDOR}\{YOUR_MODULE}\Model\Quote;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor;

class Plugin
{

    /** @var  CustomerRepositoryInterface */
    private $_customerRepository;

    /** @var  AddressRepositoryInterface */
    private $_addressRepository;


    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface  $addressRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    }


    /**
     * Interceptor which always sets the default billing address of a customer as the quote/order billing address
     * @param Interceptor      $subject
     * @param AddressInterface $address
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSetBillingAddress(Interceptor $subject, AddressInterface $address = null)
    {
        $customerId = $address->getCustomerId();

        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);

        /** @var Address $defaultAddress */
        $defaultAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();

        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository */
        try {
            //This is our Customer Address
            $defaultBillingAddress = $this->_addressRepository->getById($defaultAddressId);

            //Convert the Customer Address to a Quote Address
            //Using the ObjectManager is bad practice, use DI instead, but how?
            $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $quoteBillingAddress */
            $quoteBillingAddress = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address');
            $quoteBillingAddress->importCustomerAddressData($defaultBillingAddress);

            $address = $quoteBillingAddress;
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            //Address not found?
        }


        return [$address];
    }

}
```

I feel this solution is still sub optimal. I hope an interceptor won't be necessary, but maybe this is of use to anyone.

Comment: It works great. But currently the function gets also called when I try to add something into the cart. Can you let me know what other files your module has? di.xml?

Comment: I actually had to put the _customerRepostitory->getById($customerId) also into a try catch block so i could add items to the cart, then it works fine thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @nbjohan answer here is code which will set the default billing address also when a customer is adding another shipping address in the checkout process.

```
<?php

namespace {YOUR_VENDOR}\{YOUR_MODULE}\Model\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;

class Plugin
{
    /** @var  Monolog */
    private $_logger;

    /** @var  AddressRepositoryInterface */
    private $_addressRepository;

    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     * @param Monolog $logger
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface  $addressRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Monolog $logger,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    }

    public function aroundSetBillingAddress(Quote $subject, callable $proceed, AddressInterface $address)
    {
      $customer = $subject->getCustomer();
      $defaultAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
      try {
          // This is our Customer default billing Address
          /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository */
          $defaultBillingAddress = $this->_addressRepository->getById($defaultAddressId);
          $old = $subject->getBillingAddress();
          if (!empty($old)) {
              $old->importCustomerAddressData($defaultBillingAddress);
          } else {
              $subject->addAddress($defaultBillingAddress);
          }
      } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
          // Address not found?
          return $proceed($address);
      }

      return $subject;
    }
}
```